# Average date of last line edit

Tags: git, refactoring

git blame  gives me date of last edit of every line in file.
It is possible to get average (or something similar) line edit date from whole file?

In other words I want have tool to evaluate how old is particular file. It can be helpful to decide which file potentially require some of refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git blame --line-porcelain | grep "committer-time" | awk '{ sum += $2; n++ } END { if (n > 0) printf "%f\n", sum / n; }'
```

This works for me. Prints the average of commit timestamps.

Comment: I know the question is pretty old, but came here from google, so thought someone else also may.

Comment: git blame <file> --line-porcelain | grep "committer-time" | awk '{ sum += $2; n++ } END { if (n > 0) printf "%f\n", sum / n; }' | awk '{print "@"$1}' | xargs date -ud
Above command works for me. It gives date in human readable format.